# puppeteer - how to intercept requests and responses only from a certain url in nodejs

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I'm using puppeteer to automatize spotify login and tracks search and play from a node cli script. since I'm intercepting requests, I want to log only the urls like the one above

`https://audio-akp-quic-control-spotify-com.akamaized.net/audio/cb8daa71ccc075db7c559871bdc4?__token__=exp=1614258319~hmac=30c6d8c5676fb472ec33fd5c8ca6331ee756daf9f69096e214`

Usually in a chrome extension I can use a glob to target only the desired url for example: `https://audio-akp-quic-control-spotify-com.akamaized.net/audio/*`, how I can achive the same result in node and log only the request / responses from the urls I need?

Comment: Check the example given in official docs for [page.setRequestInterception](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pagesetrequestinterceptionvalue). It shows how to intercept requests based on request URL. This should get you started.

Comment: @ggorlen thank you, I'm looking at the solutions provided in the question you've linked.